# Question About Tab Notation

Tags: notation, electric-guitar, tablature, ties

Maybe an obvious question, but I ran across notation in the tabs for a song that I wasn't exactly familiar with. I'm fairly familiar with a lot of guitar notation, even though I primarily play drums, but this notation is confusing to me. It's a slur mark, but it isn't indicated a hammer-on or a pull off because there's no other note being indicated on the tab. It's  just the first note, then slurs of varying lengths. I mean after the harm on 7 with the full bend, it just goes off into nothing. Is it some odd notation for let ring?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't slurs, those are **ties**. So yes, it's notation for "let ring". Honestly, similar ties are used so often in the excerpt in your picture (in fact, such ties start getting used in Bar 8) that the note stems in the tab look close to outright deceiving to me: they do help you keep the rhythm, but the music won't sound like you play a new note on every stem in practice.